# Javascript calculation returns 'on' when calculating percentage of variable

Tags: javascript, html

I constructed a calculation form out of different modules and got it to work except for 1 element.

The overall calculation is build up as (value + value = total), and the values are all regular numbers.

However, the last bit I added is a 'percentage'-value which is 10% of the first value in the form. So as an example:
    Value 1 = 50,
    Percent value 2 = 5 (10% of value 1),
    Total = 55

In my code this looks as follows:

```
var NonTrans_prices = new Array();
NonTrans_prices["NoneNon"] = 0;
NonTrans_prices["LemonNon"] = 5994;
NonTrans_prices["CustardNon"] = 7076;

function NonTrans() {
    var NonTransPrice = 0;
    var theForm = document.forms["GRANADANEO"];
    var selectedFilling = theForm.elements["NonTrans"];
    NonTransPrice = NonTrans_prices[selectedFilling.value];
    return NonTransPrice;
}
var price = NonTrans_prices;
var percentage = 10;
var costs = (price * percentage) / 100;
var optionprice = price + percentage;

function optionprice1() {
    var inscriptionPrice = 0;
    var theForm = document.forms["GRANADANEO"];
    var optionprice = theForm.elements["optionprice"];
    if (optionprice.checked == true) {
        inscriptionPrice = optionprice.value;
    }
    return inscriptionPrice;
}

function calculateTotal() {
    var cakePrice = NonTrans() + optionprice1();
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display = 'block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price: " + cakePrice + " \u20ac";
}
```

*The NonTransPrice is connected to a dropdown box, and the optionprice1 is connected to a checkbox.

As soon as I tick the checkbox containing the 10% value, the letters "on" are added to the total price. What's going wrong?

**Sorry forgot to post the entire code so that you guys/girls can test: https://jsfiddle.net/6a55tm4j/
For some reason it doesn't show the total value in jsfiddle, on the live website I am testing on it does so that's not really a problem I am facing live.
Live link: http://axesseurope.be/appalacarte/Calculator/axess_calculator.html

This is the HTML code containing the parts affected by the .js code:

```
<body onload='hideTotal()'>
<div id="wrap">
<form action="" id="GRANADANEO" onsubmit="return false;">
<div>
<div class="cont_order">
<fieldset>
<table><tr><td>
<label >NonTrans</label>
<select id="NonTrans" name='NonTrans' onchange="calculateTotal()">
<option value="NoneNon">Select Dimensions</option>
<option value="LemonNon">3,00 6,40 0,85</option>
<option value="CustardNon">3,00 7,50 0,85</option>
</select>
</td></tr></table>
<hr>
<br/>    
<label>Granada Neo Opties Algemeen</label>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" id="optionprice" name='optionprice' onclick="calculateTotal()" />
<label for='optionprice' class="inlinelabel">optionprice</label>
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" id="SchuifdeurVoorzijde" name='SchuifdeurVoorzijde' onclick="calculateTotal()" />
<label for='SchuifdeurVoorzijde' class="inlinelabel">Schuifdeur in voorzijde</label>
</p>
<div id="totalPrice"></div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</div>  
</form>
```

Comment: any HTML to play with?

Comment: `optionprice` seems to be a checkbox, its value will be `"on"` when it is checked.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Sorry mate forgot about that, just added it in the post

Comment: @JozefLegény That sounds darn logical to me, however the purpose is to show the value of the calculation instead of the value of the box (on/off). You have any idea how I can accomplish that?

Comment: @YassineLamlih: No you didn't. You may have added a link to it, but it has to be **in** the question, not just linked.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Is it ok to paste the entire source code in the post?

Comment: @YassineLamlih: Yes, provided it's a [mcve]. In fact, it's encouraged, ideally with a web tech question do it as a Stack Snippet (the `<>` toolbar button). If it's a [mcve]. If it isn't, then that's the next step: Making one.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Checkboxes have a value of "on" when they are selected. Ensure that your checkboxes include a value attribute that contains the meaningful data they represent. For example:

```
     <input type="checkbox" id="chkSomeId" name="chkSomeID" 
            value="someValueToBeWhenChecked">
```

This is true of radio buttons as well.

So, in your code, this line:

```
 inscriptionPrice = optionprice.value
```

is most-likely accessing the value of either a checkbox or radio button that does not have an explicit value set for it, but is checked.

Also, remember that all values pulled from HTML come into JavaScript as strings, so if you need to do math with those values, you'll want to use `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()`.

UPDATE: now that you have posted your HTML, I see this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="optionprice" name='optionprice' onclick="calculateTotal()" />
```

which is exactly what I suspected. My above answer will correct the problem. That checkbox needs a value set for it.

**UPDATE**:

In your following code:

```
 //Add percentage
 var price = NonTrans_prices;
 var percentage = 10;
 var costs = (price * percentage) / 100;
 var optionprice = price + percentage;

 //Add percentage
 function optionprice1()
 {
     var inscriptionPrice=0;
     //Get a refernce to the form id="GRANADANEO"
     var theForm = document.forms["GRANADANEO"];
     //Get a reference to the checkbox id="optionprice"
     var optionprice = theForm.elements["optionprice"];
     //If they checked the box set inscriptionPrice to 20
     if(optionprice.checked==true){
         inscriptionPrice=optionprice.value;
     }
     //finally we return the inscriptionPrice
     return inscriptionPrice;
 }
```

I think that you should take the 4 `var` lines and include them in the function.
I think that the first line: `var price = NonTrans_prices;` is incorrect, because it sets the variable `price` to the actual array of NonTrans prices, rather than looking up a particular price, which would be:

```
 var price = NonTrans_prices[document.getElementById("nonTransList").value];
```

Then, your problem is that if the optionPrice checkbox is checked, you are trying to access the value of the checkbox, which (as I've said) doesn't explicitly exist, so you get "on" (because the checkbox is checked). What you should be doing is setting the price to result of the 10% calculation that was just done on the line above. So the final function looks like this:

```
 function optionprice1()
 {
     var chkOptionPrice = document.getElementById("optionprice");
     var lstNonTransValue = document.getElementById(NonTrans).value;

     var inscriptionPrice = 0;

     if(optionprice.checked === true){

      // Look up the price in the array that matches the dropdown list's value
      var price = NonTrans_prices[lstNonTransValue];

      // Do the math to calculate 10% of the original price
      var percentage = 10;
      inscriptionPrice = (price * percentage) / 100;;
     }

     // finally we return the inscriptionPrice
     return inscriptionPrice;
 }
```

You were close, but the thing that, I think, tripped you up was that you created a variable with the same name as your checkbox and after doing the calculation, you should have been trying to get the value of your variable, but you were trying to get the value of the checkbox, which isn't where the answer was.

I hope that I've understood what you wanted correctly, but even if my algorithm is off, I hope you can see that you don't want to be using the value of the checkbox to get your answer, since it doesn't store any value.

Comment: That wasn't me, I have added a bit of the HTML code and in there you can see that I have another checkbox which does do what it's suppose to do and that's communicating it's value. For some reason the same logic didn't apply for the 'optionprice' checkbox.

Comment: @YassineLamlih You are not accessing the "SchuifdeurVoorzijde" checkbox value in your JavaScript. You are only using it to invoke a function. That's why that one works. But, you are accessing the value of the optionprice check box value in your code and it has no value set for it, so you get "on" when it's checked.

Comment: Correction, I didn't read your edited post give me a few to process that what you stated thanks in advance!

Comment: @YassineLamlih You are NOT getting the value of the "SchuifdeurVoorzijde" check box with that code. You are determining if it is checked, by looking at it's checked property.

Comment: It's CRAZY that there are two down votes on this when the OP has shown that my explanation and answer are CORRECT.

Comment: Ok so how would I give 'value=' a proper value when my goal is: 10% of dropdownbox selection?

Comment: You need to set that value with JavaScript that triggers when the change event of the dropdown element occurs.  What you want to do is use the checkboxes and the dropdown as triggers that modify the variable values in your JavaScript, rather than store those values in checkboxes.

Comment: I'm gonna be completely honest with you, I have no idea what you are talking about. I managed to copy-paste and modify a small calculator script into the following: http://axesseurope.be/appalacarte/Calculator/axess_calculator.html and as you can see everything but the optionprice checkbox functions

Comment: I'm sorry that you don't know what I'm talking about, but it is the reason your code isn't working.  Please give me a little time as I am working on fixing your code so I can demonstrate the correct way to do this.

Comment: I must agree with you, as I stated I'm a complete noob that knows how to Google and to modify scripts up to a certain extent. It wasn't my purpose, but would be a great help if you could do that. Thanks in advance again.

Comment: @YassineLamlih - Ok, I'm working my way through your code (updating a lot of it to use proper standards and take advantage of jQuery, which you are using), but it all comes back to this line `inscriptionPrice = optionprice.value;` I need you to tell me what you think the value of the optionprice checkbox should be if someone were to check it because you do not have that value embedded into your code. This is the essence of the issue. There is a comment above this line that says it should be 20, is that correct?

Comment: No I'm sorry I was sloppy enough not to remove the old comments of the original script.. the value of the optionprice checkbox needs to be: 10% of the value of var NonTrans_prices
So as soon as the second option in the NonTrans dropdown box is selected, the value of that selection is 5994. The optionprice checkbox should return 599.4 in this case.

Comment: @YassineLamlih  Please take a careful look at my latest update.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed description you've motivated me to look into the differences more in order to avoid this and I actually understand what I did wrong. If it was up to me your answer should've been rated + at least 10 times by now, again thanks for the effort mate!

Comment: For some reason it didnt show a total price, I made this now no idea whether its any good though but it works:
function optionprice1()
{
var chkOptionPrice = document.getElementById("optionprice");
var theForm = document.forms["GRANADANEO"];
var selectedFilling = theForm.elements["NonTrans"];
var lstNonTransValue = NonTrans_prices[selectedFilling.value];
var inscriptionPrice = 0;
if(optionprice.checked === true){
var price = NonTrans_prices[selectedFilling.value];
var percentage = 10;
inscriptionPrice = (price * percentage) / 100;
}
return inscriptionPrice;
}

Answer (score 0):

In the end with the help of Scott Marcus this was the solution:

```
function optionprice1()
{
 var chkOptionPrice = document.getElementById("optionprice");
 var theForm = document.forms["GRANADANEO"];
 var selectedFilling = theForm.elements["NonTrans"];
 var lstNonTransValue = NonTrans_prices[selectedFilling.value];

 var inscriptionPrice = 0;

 if(optionprice.checked === true){

  // Look up the price in the array that matches the dropdown list's value
  var price = NonTrans_prices[selectedFilling.value];

  // Do the math to calculate 10% of the original price
  var percentage = 10;
  inscriptionPrice = (price * percentage) / 100;
 }

 // finally we return the inscriptionPrice
 return inscriptionPrice;
 }
```

Comment: Would have wished you marked my answer as the correct answer, since what you posted was my answer that I posted to you.

Comment: My bad I thought I could assign both answers as correct, still new to stackoverflow